# Property of inversion map on invertible operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, frechet-derivative

Given $X,Y$ two Banach spaces, I know the set of bounded operators $L(X,Y)$ is Banach with the operator norm $\|A\|=\sup_{\|x\|\leq1}\|Ax\|$. I know the set of bounded operators with bounded inverse $\mathrm{Inv}(X,Y)$ is open in $L(X,Y)$ with the norm topology. I have proved that, if $J(A):=A^{-1}$ is the inversion map, then it is Fréchet differentiable and $\mathrm{d}J(A)(B)=-A^{-1}BA^{-1}$. But the exercise I was given, in the midst of trying my luck at which I proved the above differentiability, was to prove $J$ was *smooth*. So I tried the second derivative, and I am stuck. I am supposed to find a bilinear form for which:

$$\lim_{\|T\|\to0}\frac{\|-(A+T)^{-1}B(A+T)^{-1}+A^{-1}BA^{-1}-D(T,B)\|}{\|T\|}=0,$$

and then $D$ would be the second derivative of $J$ at $A$. But how can I? I mean, If I try adding stuff to break the sum into two I get a piece which I can get back to the limit for the first derivative in the identity, but the other piece I get is similar but with $(A+T)^{-1}$ on the right (or left depending on the terms I add), meaning I cannot just stick it into the differential since it is not linear in $T$. Any hints? Is there any sensible way of proving smoothness? Perhaps inductively?

Comment: Maybe you can do something like a product rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using what you have,
$$
            (A+B)^{-1}-A^{-1}= -A^{-1}BA^{-1}+o(B).
$$
So the derivative of the derivative examines
\begin{align}
      &-(A+T)^{-1}B(A+T)^{-1}\\
  &=-\{ -A^{-1}TA^{-1}+A^{-1}+o(T)\}B\{-A^{-1}TA^{-1}+A^{-1}+o(T)\} \\
  &=+A^{-1}TA^{-1}BA^{-1}+A^{-1}BA^{-1}TA^{-1}+A^{-1}BA^{-1}+o(T)
\end{align}
And that looks about right. The required symmetry between $T$ and $B$ is there, for example. So the second derivative would be
$$
        D^2J(T,B)=A^{-1}TA^{-1}BA^{-1}+A^{-1}BA^{-1}TA^{-1}
$$

Comment: So to go on one would expect following derivatives calculated in $T_1,\dotsc,T_n$ to be the simmetrization of $A^{-1}T_1A^{-1}\dots A^{-1}T_n$, and I even have an idea of how to do that by induction.

Comment: You have a multilinear function evaluated in all arguments at $A^{-1}$. It's going to be an ugly induction.

Comment: @MickG : It should be noted that each argument of the multilinear function is evaluated with $A^{-1}-A^{-1}T_kA^{-1}+o(T_k)$ and only one term in the evaluation will be replaced with $-A^{-1}T_kA^{-1}$ because higher order $T_k$  terms don't count in the derivative.